# Is it possible in highcharts to have 2 charts, sharing the same x-axis, but next to one another?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I found this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tungwaiyip/F3pts/6/

But that’s not what I want. I need to have something similar but with the charts sharing the x-axis.

```
        top: 300;
```

The above setting in the yAxis does the trick on the y axis but I can't see anything like that for the x-axis.

Is it possible in highcharts to have 2 charts, sharing the same x-axis, but next to one another?

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PcWSu/

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. Do you want the charts from your example to be next to each other, meaning e.g. the x-axis has a range from 0-10 and the line chart goes from 0-5 and the column/bar chart goes from 5-10? Something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same properties you can use for xAxis (top, left, width, height), see: http://jsfiddle.net/F3pts/7/

```
xAxis: [{
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    width :150
}, {
    offset: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    width :150,
    left: 230
}],
```

Comment: Why thank you Sir. I did try it and it didn't work for me but I obviously did something wrong. I scanned the docs for I couldn't find the "left" parameter in the xAxis. I only found "top" on the yAxis in the HighStock API. Your solution works and your help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey Paweł Fus I need to have more than two graph side by side is it possible ??

Comment: Yes, it is. Add more xAxis, and for each set width and left the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate but I am trying so. Can you give me  js fiddle please I am really stuck at this. I need to get it done fast.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/ur6zYstBh here is the link of what kind of chart I am looking for. Paweł Fus

Comment: Try to use nested categories in your case: https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories

Comment: Paweł Fus hey mate How do I set the grid width dynamically like for one scenario I have 3 x axis and for another 4 can we set the left property dynamically ?? so that chart will look properly.

Comment: Is there a way to find where the XAxis[0] ends? If the chart is generated dynamically and you can't hardcode the left value (left:230)

Comment: Hmm.. if you set margin left directly, it would be sum of that margin and width of axis. Otherwise you need to get that value from `chart.plotLeft + xAxis.width`, but plotLeft is generated after chart is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can  go through this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajaytripathi10/z8mrwhxz/) where in you can see shared tooltip with multiple X and Y axis. Hope this will help.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Shared tooltip chart'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime',
            id: 'x1'
        }, {
            type: 'datetime',
            id: 'x2',
            opposite: true
        }],
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function () {
                var tooltip = '';
                var i, len;
                tooltip += '<small>Apple</small>';
                tooltip += '<table>';
                for (i = 0, len = 4; i < len; i++) {
                        if(this.points[i] != undefined){
                if(this.points[i].series.name.indexOf('Apple') >= 0){
                    tooltip += '<tr>';
                    tooltip += '<td style="color: ' + this.points[i].series.color + '">\u25CF</td>';
                    tooltip += '<td>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.points[i].x) + ':</td>';
                    tooltip += '<td style="text-align: right"><b>' + this.points[i].y + '</b></td>';
                    tooltip += '</tr>';
                    }
                    }
                }
                tooltip += '</table>';
                tooltip += '<small>Mango</small>';
                tooltip += '<table>';
                for (i = 0, len = 4; i < len; i++) {
                        if(this.points[i] != undefined){
                if(this.points[i].series.name.indexOf('Mango') >= 0){
                    tooltip += '<tr>';
                    tooltip += '<td style="color: ' + this.points[i].series.color + '">\u25CF</td>';
                    tooltip += '<td>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.points[i].x) + ':</td>';
                    tooltip += '<td style="text-align: right"><b>' + this.points[i].y + '</b></td>';
                    tooltip += '</tr>';
                    }
                    }
                }
                tooltip += '</table>';
                return tooltip;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Apple',
            id: 'series1',
            xAxis: 'x1',
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 1, 0],
            pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 10)
        }, {
            name: 'Apple New',
            id: 'series2',
            //linkedTo: 'series1',
            xAxis: 'x2',
            color: 'rgba(255, 180, 180, 1.0)',
            data: [4, 5, 5, 6, 1, 3, 4],
            pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 17)
        },{
            name: 'Mango',
            id: 'series3',
            xAxis: 'x1',
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)',
            data: [15, 13, 14, 17, 16, 11, 10],
            pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 10)
        }, {
            name: 'Mango New',
            id: 'series4',
            //linkedTo: 'series1',
            xAxis: 'x2',
            color: 'rgba(255, 180, 180, 1.0)',
            data: [14, 15, 15, 16, 11, 13, 14],
            pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 2, 17)
        }]
    });
});
```