# HighCharts multiple x series data for line graph

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on a reporting system where it takes all the data from backend and represent in graph. Using highcharts I have completed on graph which was simple line graph 24 hrs spread over the x axis and each line represents date.Now the problem is getting the second graph ready. I want the second graph to look like this `http://screencast.com/t/ur6zYstBh`.

Here as you can see multiple x axis series is there where each series consist of 24 hr and represent to a particular  date. I tried finding the example or anything close to it but didn't succeed. I am open to any solution just want to the graph completed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question may be what you are looking for:

[Is it possible in highcharts to have 2 charts, sharing the same x-axis, but next to one another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333993/is-it-possible-in-highcharts-to-have-2-charts-sharing-the-same-x-axis-but-next/16336502#16336502)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will surely give it a try :)