# HighCharts alternating dual xaxis

Tags: highcharts

Similar to this question: [Is it possible in highcharts to have 2 charts, sharing the same x-axis, but next to one another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333993/is-it-possible-in-highcharts-to-have-2-charts-sharing-the-same-x-axis-but-next)

Is it possible to have two xaxis, but instead of side-by-side or on top of each other, to have them alternate. i.e. first column is from axis0, second is from axis1

Comment: Could you attach mockup how it should look like ?

Comment: I have to ask why you would want to do this?  It seems like something that there must be a better way to accomplish, honestly...

Comment: This was a request not what I want. Display a data set and have the option to add an additional dataset for comparison, but have the values pair side by side Jan from 2012 next to Jan from 2011 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Since you did not provide any code on what you had tried here is a basic [example](http://jsfiddle.net/42UXs/). Do something like:

```
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Europe Site Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    }],
```

As far as alternating column to whatever axis you can handle that by how you add the series and what axis you assign them to.

Comment: What about the xaxis ?

Comment: To do this with the xAxis it would be similar.  Add another xAxis, then in the series tell it which one to use. Note that the axis are 0-based. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/S2srp/

Comment: Is there a way to combine the two into one axis. Something like Jan Jan Feb Feb ...

Comment: Yes, but, I must ask why? If you are going to have things on the same axis why double up the labels? To do this you can set `opposite` to false (or remove that property as the default is false). You would then have to add an `offset` of some amount so the labels do not overwrite each other. Then you would have to do more formatting trickery to handle extra-long category names, etc etc. You can set the offset to some amount that is less than full opposite value as well. Trying playing around with the jsFiddle and various properties.