# HighCharts Boxplot side by side Xaxis

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to do something similar to this: [Is it possible in highcharts to have 2 charts, sharing the same x-axis, but next to one another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333993/is-it-possible-in-highcharts-to-have-2-charts-sharing-the-same-x-axis-but-next/16336502#16336502)

http://jsfiddle.net/F3pts/7/

However with boxplots it seems that adding a series even to another X Axis makes the boxplots in the first axis "squish" together as if they were being added to the same axis

see code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jK6pb/2/ . Series 'third' is on Axis 1 but still affects the boxplots on Axis 0. Try toggling hide and show. You can see I added space between the two axis to make sure it wasnt the axis causing the effect

```
chart.get('third').show()
```

Use case: Series 'Observation1' and 'Observation2' are related datasets and the boxplots are drawn together. 'Observastions3' is an unrelated data set and should be drawn on the side in its own axis

[image: side by side comparison]

Comment: Could it be a bug? What is the point of adding a series to another axis if it will affect the other series

Comment: Looking at the image it appears to me that you have 2 charts sharing the yAxis but different xAxis. My question is why? What is different about the 2 xAxis? If it is another set of experiment sets just make it a new series. The first two series are "squished" because they share the same xAxis location. What is your expected output supposed to look like?

Comment: They shouldnt share the same xAxis location, they are on separate Axis. See here with different categories: http://jsfiddle.net/jK6pb/3/. Even with a second YAxis the same affect happens. They are two separate data sets that the user would like to display side by side. I just don't want the series to be squished

Comment: To answer "Why do you want to do that, it's stupid" The user wants the ability to see the second (independent) data set side by side.

Comment: You have 3 distinct sets of data (plus a scatter series). You are setting series 'Observations' and 'Observations2' to use xAxis = 0 and series 'Observations3' to use xAxis = 1. Not saying it is stupid - I am saying I am trying to understand the usage case.

Comment: I understand. There are other ways of achieving this but what is the point of adding a second axis if the series added to that axis will affect the first axis?

Comment: Ahhh. I see it now. I had to view "full" chart image. Okay, yes, it looks like the addition of `third` makes it look like it is added and the other 2 series shift to make room for it. The `third` series also looks like it is moved to the right of center on its axis.

Comment: Yes the third series shifts to the right and the first two shift to the left as if they were going to be drawn in the same column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to achieve but require three things:

- set `grouping: false` for right series
- right plotting area is limited to one series
- series with disabled grouping need to be first series in series array.

And live example: http://jsfiddle.net/jK6pb/5/